# Adding words to a hash table in C

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, cs50

Before proceeding with **PSET5 - SPELLER** of the CS50 course, I have decided to practice with a made-up program that takes words from a file and sorts them into a Hash Table, but I think I`m doing something wrong with the Hash Function as I keep getting the following error:

```
array subscript is not an integer
   
table[hash] = n;
```

Some of the elements are taken from the task itself to understand how they work. I don`t have any previous knowledge, totally limited to the CS50 course.

Please have a look at my code and maybe give a few pointers to what I am doing wrong.
From what I understand - every new word`s first letter goes through Hash Functions and returns a number for the Bucket in which this word goes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int hash(const char *buffer);

const unsigned int LENGTH = 9;

typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node* next;
}
node;

node *table[26] = {NULL};

int hash(const char *buffer)
{
    return toupper(buffer[0]) - 'A';
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("words", "r");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char buffer[LENGTH];
        while (fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
        {
            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (n == NULL)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            strcpy(n->word, buffer);
            n->next = NULL;
            table[hash] = n;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some other issues: Your `hash(..)` function could return a negative number or a number > = 26. Consider using modulus and the like to prevent this. Your `fscanf(..)` could overfill the char `buffer` array - there's nothing to stop that from happening. Your tail pointer `next` in the struct node is not initialized (ideally to `nullptr`) - how will you know when you arrive at the end of your linked list? Good luck. The best way to learn is to try it like this.

Comment: Not sure how to understand "Your fscanf(..) could overfill the char buffer array - there's nothing to stop that from happening". And also isn`t n->next = NULL; initializing my next pointer?

Comment: yes you're right on the `n->next = NULL`, I missed that. The `fscanf(...)` is going to write as many bytes as it finds into the `buffer` array, that could be more than LENGTH. `fscanf(...)` doesn't know the length of `buffer` to stop itself from doing that.

Comment: Hmm.. is this why I keep getting Segmentation Fault?

Comment: Use `fscanf(file,"%23s",buffer)` , it will scan at most 23 non-whitespace characters. Look up the format arguments for `fscanf(...)` there will be choices that help you further.

Comment: I have actually changed `char buffer[LENGTH];` to `char buffer[LENGTH + 1];` and it solved the problem. I only did it randomly without any logic applied.. I`ll have a look into your suggestion as well. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function `hash(..)` , it is not a variable.
Your line should be:

```
table[ hash(n->word) ] = n;
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do we use "n->word" and not "buffer"?

Comment: @87lst buffer is the argument name. n -> word has the value you want hash(…) to work with